# I need help in entering two string in a class and getting its output

Tags: c++, string

When I am trying to enter the two string name `str1`and `str2` in program it is giving me error

```
cpp|19|error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'int' in return|

|26|error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'int' in return|
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{

    string str1,str2;

    public:

    void set_first_name(string a)
    {
    str1=a;
    }
    int get_first_name()
    {
        return str1;
    }
    void set_last_name(string b){
        str2=b;
    }
    int get_last_name()
    {
        return str2;
    }


    };

    int main() {
    string first_name, last_name;

    cin >>  first_name >> last_name ;   //Entering the string 

    Student st;


    st.set_first_name(first_name);      //setting the string 1 in class Student
    st.set_last_name(last_name);        //setting the string 2 in class Student


    cout << st.get_last_name() << ", " << st.get_first_name() << "\n";  // calling first and second string

    cout << st.to_string();      //I don't know what 

    return 0;
    }
```

**new problem is**

```
class Student
{

    string str1,str2;
    int ag, st;

    public:
    void set_first_name(string a)
    {
    str1=a;
    }
    string get_first_name()
    {
        return str1;
    }
    void set_last_name(string b){
        str2=b;
    }
    string get_last_name()
    {
        return str2;
    }
    void set_age(int ag1)
    {
        ag=ag1;
    }
    int get_age(){
    return ag;}
    void set_standard(int st1){
    st=st1;}
    int get_standard(){
    return st};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Student& student)
{
    out << "("<<student.ag<<","<<student.str1 << "," << student.str2 << "," << student.st << ")";
    return out;
}
    int get_standard(void)
    {
        return st;
    }
};

int main() {
    int age, standard;
    string first_name, last_name;

    cin >> age >> first_name >> last_name >> standard;

    Student st;
    st.set_age(age);
    st.set_standard(standard);
    st.set_first_name(first_name);
    st.set_last_name(last_name);

    cout << st.get_age() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_last_name() << ", " << st.get_first_name() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_standard() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    std::cout << st;
    return 0;
}
```

Errors are

```
error: expected ';' before '}' token

error: 'st' was not declared in this scope

error: expected declaration before '}' token
```

Comment: ***cout << st.to_string();      //I don't know what*** Should be easy for you to create a function to_string(); that concatenates the two strings and puts a space between. and returns that. make sure you return type is std::string not int.

Comment: You define functions that return an `int`, but attempt to return a `std::string` from them. Your compiler's error states the same thing. What about this compilation error is unclear to you, and you're asking about?

Comment: @drescherjm you are telling right and I fixed the return type but the error  now is    error: 'class Student' has no member named 'to_string'|

Comment: @aadeez What do you want to do with  ```st.to_string()``` ?

Comment: concatenate the str1 and str2

Comment: @aadeez, now you need to implement the member function `Student::to_string()`. C++ doesn't automatically add such functions like how it happens in Java, where every class gets a `toString()` inherited from the `java.lang.Object` class.

Comment: I said create a to_string function.

Comment: Solution for new problem: get rid of get_standard(void) after your class and place semicolon before the } in get_standard in class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because return type of getter functions is int instead of string:

```
string get_first_name()
    {
        return str1;
    }
string get_last_name()
    {
        return str2;
    }
```

Update: Answering to question from comments.

```
class Student
{

    string str1,str2;
    int age, st;

    public:
    void set_first_name(string a)
    {
    str1=a;
    }
    int get_first_name()
    {
        return str1;
    }
    void set_last_name(string b){
        str2=b;
    }
    int get_last_name()
    {
        return str2;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Student& student)
{
    out << "("<<student.age<<","<<student.str1 << "," << student.str2 << "," << student.st << ")";
    return out;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
int main()
{
    Student me;
    std::cout << me;
}
```

Comment: @NixonN how do I return string??

Comment: Just place string in return type of a getter function as I do. Or what do you mean actually?

Comment: @NixonN Can you help in one more thing I want to get output like this on last line (15,john,carmack,10) how do I get this

Comment: You can overload operator<<. But what is 15 and 10?

Comment: They are integers which I get from user 1st is age and second is standard thanks for overload but can you please tell me how?

Comment: In your class: friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Student& st);  And then definition in the global scope after the class. out << "(" << st.age << "," << st.str1 << ","<<st.str2 << "," << st.standard << ")"; return out;

Comment: actually I am beginner so I can't understand what are you saying @NixonN

Comment: So, what variables used for age and standard?

Comment: integers are ag,st;

Comment: @NixonN are you here?

Comment: Yes, I am here.

Comment: @NixonN integers name are ag and st

Comment: You can change it in my code : ) Nothing will change except the variable name. By the way, I added the code that will solve your problem

Comment: @NixonN Hey bro I am still getting error should I send you the code??

Comment: it would really help you if you spend some time and learn about the meaning of error messages. Many times the compiler tells you what to do.

Comment: @NixoN I don't have the privilege to send chats should I post the code in comment

Comment: @aadeez You can edit your post but you shouldn't delete first part of your post. You should just append it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Student{
    private:
        int age;
        int standard;
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
    public:
        void set_age(int a){
            age = a;
        }
        int get_age(){
            return age;
        }

        void set_standard(int b){
            standard = b;
        }
        int get_standard(){
            return standard;
        }

        void set_first_name(string c){
            first_name = c;
        }
        string get_first_name(){
            return first_name;
        }

        void set_last_name(string d){
            last_name = d;
        }
        string get_last_name(){
            return last_name;
        }

        string to_string()
        {
            stringstream ss;
            char c = ',';
            ss<<age<<c<<first_name<<c<<last_name<<c<<standard;
            return ss.str();
        }
};


int main() {
    int age, standard;
    string first_name, last_name;

    cin >> age >> first_name >> last_name >> standard;

    Student st;
    st.set_age(age);
    st.set_standard(standard);
    st.set_first_name(first_name);
    st.set_last_name(last_name);

    cout << st.get_age() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_last_name() << ", " << st.get_first_name() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_standard() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << st.to_string();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return type of your functions is int, not string.

Answer (score 0):

In your first error case, you are trying to return `std::string` objects where `int` vales are expected.  Your `get_first_name()` and `get_last_name()` getters need to return `std::string` instead of `int`, eg:

```
string get_first_name()
{
    return str1;
}

string get_last_name()
{
    return str2;
}
```

In your second error case, you have several syntax errors in your code.  You have several syntax elements that are either missing or in the wrong places.

The code should look more like this instead:

```cpp
class Student
{
    std::string str1, str2;
    int ag, st;

public:
    void set_first_name(std::string a)
    {
        str1 = a;
    }

    std::string get_first_name() const // <-- add const here
    {
        return str1;
    }

    void set_last_name(std::string b)
    {
        str2 = b;
    }

    std::string get_last_name() const // <-- add const here
    {
        return str2;
    }

    void set_age(int ag1)
    {
        ag = ag1;
    }

    int get_age() const // <-- add const here
    {
        return ag;
    }

    void set_standard(int st1)
    {
        st = st1;
    }

    int get_standard() const // <-- add const here
    {
        return st; // <-- ; needed here!
    } // <-- remove ; from here!

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Student&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Student& student)
{
    out << "(" << student.ag << "," << student.str1 << "," << student.str2 << "," << student.st << ")";
    return out;
}

// <-- remove entire get_standard() from here!

// <-- remove }; from here!

int main()
{
    int age, standard;
    string first_name, last_name;

    cin >> age >> first_name >> last_name >> standard;

    Student st;
    st.set_age(age);
    st.set_standard(standard);
    st.set_first_name(first_name);
    st.set_last_name(last_name);

    cout << st.get_age() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_last_name() << ", " << st.get_first_name() << "\n";
    cout << st.get_standard() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    std::cout << st;
    return 0;
}
```